# How to get the arguments from an Action?

Tags: c#

I have a method that accepts an Action with a signature like:

```
public void DoSomething(Action code);
```

then I would call this method like:

```
DoSomething(()=> CallSomething("A","B","C");
```

In the DoSomething method, how can I get the argument values?

Another thing to consider is that CallSomething can potentially **have optional parameters**, meaning I can't just change the signature of DoSomething to -> `Expression<Action>`

All I need to do is get the argument values, I'm interested in any method that can work.

I've already tried to create a new method which accepts `Expression<Action>` then pass the Action through (From DoSomething), but the arguments weren't populated.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: I don't think it's gonna be very simple because within the `DoSomething` function, `code` is just some sort of function pointer; you don't always know that it's a lambda that calls another function. I feel like you'd have to use Reflection to disassemble the lambda and look for the function call, but even then you're doing some rather icky stuff.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do, and why do you think methods that take `Action` (or `Expression<Action>`) are the way to do it? And why would `Expression<Action>` prevent you from using optional parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is *you don't want to*.

Your method accepts an `Action` delegate. It's saying "I only want something to call that has no arguments and returns no value".

If you need to pass arguments to the function, either use a different delegate, or pass them as arguments directly.

Think about this *without* the lambda. You have an interface that has a single method, `Act` that takes no arguments and returns no value.

```
DoSomething(IMyInterface myInterface)
{
  myInterface.Act(); // How do I get the arguments of some method that `Act` calls?
}
```

Does this make any sense whatsoever? Would you expect to be able to disassemble the whole instance that's passed in `myInterface`, find its `Act` method, go through all of the methods that are called from there and intercept their arguments? Delegates are little but a single-method interface with a bit of state carried over.

If you need the arguments, *make them part of the public interface*. Otherwise, your abstraction has no meaning whatsoever, and you shouldn't be using it. Nobody is *forcing* you to use lambdas, and nobody is *forcing* you to pass a single lambda and no arguments, and nobody is *forcing* you to use `Action` in particular. They are all simple tools - if they don't fit your task, *don't use them*.

To answer your question more directly: you get the arguments as any other arguments. The problem is that your action *has no arguments*.

Comment: Can you give me the poor mans version please? I.e: I am passing code that can get executed right? Because it can get executed it at some point understands arguments. How then can I get the arguments?

Comment: @JL. You're not passing *code* - you're passing an interface. Sure, the class that implements that interface does have the code, but that code is already compiled by the time the `DoSomething` method is called. Even through reflection, there's no way to get to the C# code - the best you can do is interpret the IL code somehow. Maybe they aren't even arguments anymore (e.g. the call might have been inlined)! If you need to inspect the logical code, use `Expression<Action>`. Even then, it can be very hard to interpret the data in any meaningful way. *What are you trying to do*?